# Datagrid multitrigger referencing values from code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, triggers, local-variables

I'm still bloody green in WPF and have not yet fully grasped the concept behind it. I've got the following problem:

I want to set triggers in a datagrid depending on a precondition.

Example:

In my code-behind, I have a string variable, let's call it `variableString`. Now depending on the the value of `variableString`, I want to enable/disable the triggers inside a datagrid, that I have defined in XAML like:

```
if(variableString == "a")
```

then

XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5,5,0,75" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="Binding}">
  <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
             <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeColumnName}" Value="someValue">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SomeColumName}" Value="someOtherValue">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
             </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Otherwise, if

```
if(variableString == "b")
```

then

```
Do Nothing`
```

I've already tried binding the string to the datacontext of the datagrid, but that was rather contra-productive, as it removes my binding to the database.

Can anyone help me here. An example, a push in the right direction etc...

I really like the options that WPF gives you, however it's that fundamental things, that were so easy to handle in WinForms, that drive me mad in WPF.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a [MultiDataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.aspx), which allows you to base your trigger off of multiple values

```
  <MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SomeColumnName}" Value="someValue" />
      <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=variableString}" Value="A" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
  </MultiDataTrigger>
```

To find your string in the code behind, you'll probably have to use some kind of `RelativeSource` binding to find the class containing that property. My example assumes there is a public property called `variableString` on the `Window` class